# PyCharm doesn't fully recognise PyQGIS 3.18 API

Tags: pyqgis, pycharm

I use PyCharm CE 2020.3.3 (also tested with 2020.2.5) and just upgraded QGIS to the new version 3.18 (first version with Python 3.9). When I updated my start script for PyCharm and updated the Python interpreter in PyCharm, the program recognises some parts of the API, but not all:
[image: PyCharm Screenshot of import statements]
It seems that it's only finding those classes that are directly defined in the *init*.py of the qgis.core module.

Is that a QGIS bug or a PyCharm bug or related to how I loaded PyQGIS into PyCharm?
This is my start script:

```
@echo off
call C:\OSGeo4W64\bin\o4w_env.bat
call "%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass78\etc\env.bat"
@echo off
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\grass\grass78\lib
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Qt5\bin
path %PATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python39\Scripts

set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\Users\jludwig\PycharmProjects\QGIS-LRS-Rail;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python39\Scripts
set QGIS_PLUGINPATH=%QGIS_PLUGINPATH%;C:\Users\jludwig\PycharmProjects\QGIS-LRS-Rail;%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\qgis\python\plugins
set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;%QGIS_PLUGINPATH%
set PYTHONHOME=%OSGEO4W_ROOT%\apps\Python39

path %PATH%;C:\Program Files\Git\bin

start "PyCharm aware of QGIS 3" /B "C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PyCharm Community Edition 2020.2.5\bin\pycharm64.exe" %*
```

And this is the list of paths known to the Python interpreter:
[image: PyCharm Interpreter Paths]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out to be a packaging issue with the new OSGeo4W repo, Ticket is here: https://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/ticket/669

It has been fixed with qgis-3.18.1-3 and qgis-common-3.18.1-3 packages.